# Perl trim spaces from scalar or array

Tags: perl

This is a very basic Perl question but I just want to make sure the actual good practice to it.

Consider I have built a function to trim spaces from strings and I will pass to it either single scalar as string or array of strings, I have this basic working example:

```
sub trim_spaces {
    my (@out) = @_;
    for (@out) {
        s/\s+//g;
    }
    return (scalar @out >1)? @out : $out[0];
}
```

this works in the following calls:

```
trim_spaces("  These Spaces Are All Removed");
```

and

```
@str = (" Str Number 1 ", " Str Number 2 ", " Str Number 3 ");
trim_spaces(@str);
```

What I am trying to do and understand is the shortest version of this function like this:

```
sub trim_spaces {
    s/\s+//g for (@_);
    return @_;
}
```

This works only if I pass an array:

```
trim_spaces(@str);
```

but it does not work if I pass a scalar string:

```
trim_spaces("  These Spaces Are All Removed");
```

I understand it should be converted from scalar ref to array, how this can be done in the short version.

Trying to understand the best practices of Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strict best practice answer to this is to always unpack the contents of `@_` into lexical variables, first thing. Perl Best Practices provides the following (paraphrased) arguments:

- It's not self-documenting to directly access `@_`. `$_[0]`, `$_[1]`, and so on tell you nothing about what these parameters are for.
- The aliasing behavior of `@_` is easily forgotten and can be a source of hard-to-find bugs in a program. Whenever possible, avoid spooky action at a distance.
- You can verify each argument while unpacking the `@_` array.

And one argument not from PBP:

- Seeing `my $self = shift;` at the beginning of a subroutine clearly marks it as an OO method instead of an ordinary sub.

Sources: Perl Best Practices (Conway 2005), [Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::RequireArgUnpacking)'s relevant policy from PBP.

---

The elements in @_ are aliases to the original values, which means modifying them inside the subroutine will change them outside as well. The array you're returning is ignored in your examples.

If you store the string in a variable this would work:

```
my $string = '  These Spaces Are Removed   ';
trim_spaces($string); # $string is now 'TheseSpacesAreRemoved'
```

Or you could use non-destructive substitution and assign the results created by this:

```
sub trim_spaces { return map { s/\s+//gr } @_ }
my @trimmed = trim_spaces('string one', ' string two');
my ($trimmed_scalar) = trim_spaces('string three');
```

`map` will create a list of the values **r**eturned by the substitution with the `/r` flag. The parens around $trimmed_scalar are necessary; see the last example for a version where it isn't.

Alternatively, you could copy the parameters inside the subroutine into lexical variables to avoid action at a distance, which is generally better practice than directly modifying the elements of @_:

```
sub trim_spaces
{
    my @strings = @_;
    s/\s+//g for @strings;
    return @strings;
}
```

Personally, I find it nicer when the subroutine returns a value without side effects, and the `/r` flag saves me the trouble of thinking of a better name for a lexical copy. We can use `wantarray` to make it smarter in regards to the calling context:

```
sub trim_spaces
{
    return if not defined wantarray;
    return map { s/\s+//gr } @_ if wantarray;
    return shift =~ s/\s+//gr;
}
```

On a side note, `trim_spaces` would be better named `remove_whitespace` or something similar. Trimming usually means to remove leading and trailing whitespace, and the `\s` character class matches tabs, newlines, form feeds, and carriage returns in addition to spaces. Use `tr/ //dcr` to remove just spaces instead if that's what you wanted.

Comment: `you could copy the parameters inside the subroutine into lexical variables to avoid action at a distance, which is generally better practice than directly modifying the elements of @_` this is what I want to know exactly, I see a lot of code they just modify @_, so is it better or not to always modify it or use a local copy?.

Comment: @daliaessam It depends on the situation, but generally I'd go with the no-side-effects approach. It's in line with the behavior of built-ins like `uc`, `reverse`, and `split`, and you can emulate the warnings those functions give when called in void context: `use Carp; if (not defined wantarray) { carp('Useless use of trimmed_spaces in void context'); return; }`. Inside the subroutine, you have the benefit of being able to provide self-documenting names to the parameters, and many Perl programmers prefer this just because `$_[0]` is so ugly.

Comment: @daliaessam I edited my answer to provide more info on the Best Practices side of things.